# Newbie. Ant List hangs, cant load my page. Whats wrong?

Tags: tomcat, ant

So my  problem is that i am new at Java Spring and i cant start my first app from [this (official?) tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html#step1.1)

Thats log from my Bash console on my Linux Mint.
Whats going wrong ?
Any help ?

I will be really gratefull.

M.K

`

```
marcin@marcin-ThinkPad-E520 ~/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.0.M1/springapp $ ant
Buildfile: /home/marcin/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.0.M1/springapp/build.xml

usage:
     [echo] 
     [echo] springapp build file
     [echo] -----------------------------------
     [echo] 
     [echo] Available targets are:
     [echo] 
     [echo] build     --> Build the application
     [echo] deploy    --> Deploy application as directory
     [echo] deploywar --> Deploy application as a WAR file
     [echo] install   --> Install application in Tomcat
     [echo] reload    --> Reload application in Tomcat
     [echo] start     --> Start Tomcat application
     [echo] stop      --> Stop Tomcat application
     [echo] list      --> List Tomcat applications
     [echo] 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
marcin@marcin-ThinkPad-E520 ~/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.0.M1/springapp $ ant deploy
Buildfile: /home/marcin/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.0.M1/springapp/build.xml

build:
    [javac] /home/marcin/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.0.M1/springapp/build.xml:45: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

deploy:
     [copy] Copying 2 files to /home/marcin/apache-tomcat-6.0.41/webapps/springapp

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
marcin@marcin-ThinkPad-E520 ~/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.0.M1/springapp $ ant list
Buildfile: /home/marcin/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.0.M1/springapp/build.xml

list:
```

`

Answer (score 0):

it hangs at `list` because `Tomcat` is **NOT** running (See [**HERE**](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/SS03/19560-P/Docs/JWSDP/tutorial/doc/GettingStarted10.html#76780)). in your *build.xml*: `stop` appears before `list`.

```
stop      --> Stop Tomcat application  //"stop" comes before "list"
list      --> List Tomcat applications
```

when you execute the entire *build.xml* with the above sequence of targets, `stop` terminates the `Tomcat` application before `list` can list the *applications for virtual host localhost*. thus, the `Tomcat` application ***stops running*** before `list` is executed, **which is why it hangs**.

from the *tutorial page*, it seems that the sequence of targets is such that they are meant to be **executed individually**. in fact, the [tutorial page](http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html#step1.4) specifically states, before running the `list` target using the command `$ ant list`, that you need to ***start Tomcat by running `'${appserver.home}/bin/startup.bat'`***

so, you may:

- understand the *tutorial page* in detail and select your required sequence of targets, or
- do as the *tutorial page* suggests by running each target individually and see how they work, or
- shift the `list` target, from below `stop` to between `start` and `stop`.
  i.e.

  ```
  <target name="start" description="Start Tomcat application">
      <start url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
               username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
               password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
               path="/${name}"/>
  </target>
  <target name="list" description="List Tomcat applications">
      <list url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
               username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
               password="${tomcat.manager.password}"/>
  </target>    
  <target name="stop" description="Stop Tomcat application">
      <stop url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
               username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
               password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
               path="/${name}"/>
  </target>
  ```